# Excel: Search if multiple texts exist in a cell

Tags: excel

I have three columns in excel: FirstName, LastName, and a third column that contains first name, last name and maybe other characters.

Now what I want to do is **search in the third column**, and if **both FirstName and LastName** exist in **a certain cell** (since names in the third column is not in the same order as the first and second column) in the third column, return 1. Otherwise, return 0. The order of FirstName and LastName in the third column should not affect the result.

E.g. Jennifer, Smith, Smith Jennifer > this will return 1, regardless of the first/last name order

Anyone knows how to accomplish this with a formula?

Many Thanks,

To make my question more clear, here is an example.

First Name, Last Name, Name List

Jennifer , Smith , Smith Jennifer

Richard, Borland, Richard Borland (acc)  **<-this cell has other characters**

Mike , Leanne, Tom Jackson

Tom, Jackson , Leanne Mike **<-The third columns in the last two rows do not match the  order of the first two columns**

Comment: What other characters could you potentinally have? Could you have " Smith, Jennifer" in third column?

Comment: @user3885927, it could have any possible characters, like space, comma, or people's titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### NEW

#### (this searches the entire 3rd column)

So basically it took some tweaking and googling but I think I found a solution that work.  Here is the simple version of the new formula, note that this formula is *case sensitive* and there really isn't anything I can do about that since you cannot say `UPPER(C:C)` (UPPEPR() needs a single cell).  But this does work even for cells that have junk before, between, or after the joined name (and of course the name order does not matter)

```
=IF((COUNTIF(C:C,"*"& A1 & "*" & B1 &"*") + COUNTIF(C:C,"*"& B1 & "*" & A1 &"*"))>0,1,0)
```

of course as I said in my old answer, change up the references as needed.

(Small edit) I just realized this also will check part of names.  So like if someone is named "James Will" and another named "James William" and the name "James William" exists in column 3 it will show 1 for both "James Will" and "James William"

### OLD

#### (this searches the adjacent cell in the 3rd column)

If you are okay with having the result in a 4th column you can use a formula like

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A1 & " " & B1,C1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND(B1 & " " & A1,C1)),0,1),1)
```

And then just auto fill down.

Of course if your data is not in columns A-C just fix the cell references.

Now the `FIND` formula is case sensitive.  And this example uses 1 space between the first and last (or last and first) names.  If the extra characters you explained happen to appear between the names this will not work.  If that is such the case you could then use this formula:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A1,C1))),NOT(ISERROR(FIND(B1,C1)))),1,0)
```

And again, autofill down, change cell refrences as needed.

Comment: Mind you, your answer is more extensive than mine and covers possible issues that mine ignores. I guess if case sensitivity is an issue you could use UPPER () or LOWER () on all the string arguments to ignore the case?

Comment: @fraggle Yeah actually I don't know why I didn't think of using `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` because yeah that would solve the case problem.

Comment: Man, I never even considered the case problem. Tip of the hat to you for bringing it up.

Comment: Thanks @chancea, same question here, does the formula only compares two cells against one cell instead of the entire third column?

Comment: @MightyTom Sorry we both interpreted your question incorrectly.  To iterate over the entire column is a _much_ harder task.  I can look  to see if its even possible without VBA but off the top of my head I am not too confident that it is..(gonna take some time so don't expect anything for a while :D)

Comment: I'm with chancea on this, not sure that you can do it in one formula for the whole column without using vba. Possibly an array formula?

Comment: You could alter my original formula like this: =IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND($A$1,C1))),NOT(ISERROR(FIND($A$1,C1)))),1,0) and then copy down/autofill to the end of column C. This would identify any instances where both strings were found in any cell in C and then have a formula to sum the values from the formula, if it is greater than zero then you know you have a match but I'm not 100% sure I know exactly what you want to do... sorry.

Comment: @fraggle I had to just scrap everything we had and think of a different solution.  I can't even believe this actually worked and it's fairly simple.

Comment: I had to bail out as 'twas bedtime for me, I was thinking wildcards as I drifted off! Nice solution, way to go.

Comment: @chancea, I tested your new solution and it worked! Very grateful for this. However, I do see that there is a potential pitfall in this solution under some extreme circumstances. For example, if someone's name is Chae Darin, and another person's name is Michael Darinn, this algorithm will recognize the first person as existence in the last person's name.So I was wondering if there is a way to compare the third column against the first and last column to avoid this pitfall. Thanks

Comment: @MightyTom At that point you would have to guarantee that there was a specific delimiter after and before each name part in column 3.  Like each name part has a space or comma or semi-colon after, and each name part either starts at the beginning of the cell or has a space, comma, etc before.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you need is:

=IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A1,C1))),NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A1,C1)))),1,0)

Assuming Jennifer is in A1 and Smith is in B1

Comment: @chancea Unusual for me not to have fat fingers slowing me down!

Comment: Hi @fraggle, thanks for replying. Your solution is very creative. It works well when the third column contains only first and last name, but it becomes problematic when there are other text in the third column. For example, if there is a middle name in between first and last name in the third column, it will result in 0. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong here, since I am really new to excel. It looks like that the formula only compares A1 and B1 against C1, not column C, does it?

Comment: Re: middle names - no the formula will find both strings even if there are middle names, as long as those two strings exist anywhere in the third cell it will result intrue.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate formula solution:

```
=--(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(C1,"*"&A1:B1&"*"))=2)
```

Comment: this formula doesn't work under some circumstances like: first name:Chae, last name:Darin, and the last column has name Michael Darinn that contains the exact same characters.