# Excel advanced search / crossmatching names

Tags: excel, vba

I need a little help: I have to cross match Database A user names(firstname lastname) with Database B where there are some extra characters and the order is last name firstname), so the normal vlookup does not find exact match. I tried the following: I used text to column from the Database A, to have two separate column, then I tried to find the name from Database B

```
=IF(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,C1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,C1))),"yes","no")
```

This show correct result when the name is in the same line

```
A1 Tom 
B1 John
C1 John dr tom -
```

The results is true(yes), but in case:
A1 Tom B1 Jon C2 John dr tom - the result are false(No)

I need to same at Database A which is a appearing at Database 2. So I need to find the duplicated items.
Can you help me out how to correctly find what I am looking for?

[image: example Data]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366504/excel-search-if-multiple-texts-exist-in-a-cell?rq=1   - This is the closest question what I found, but these are also not working, when I want the system to check for match the entire F:F

Answer (score 0):

=VLOOKUP("*"&B1&"*" &"*"&A1&"*",F:F, 1,FALSE)  This was the answer, I managed to figure out.